# How do you print the even nos in the array using recursion traversing from the right?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Compiler version gcc 6.3.0
void print(int a[5],int n){
    n--;
    if(a[n]%2==0)
       print(a,n);
    printf("%d",a[n]);
}
int main(void){
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  print(a,5);
  return 0;
}
```

How would you print only even numbers in that array ..passing the last element obviously that code doesn't work so how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `print` even if the number is odd, or recursion stops.

Also only `printf` when the value is even, and stop when `n` index is negative or you have access violation.

Fixed:

```
void print(int a[],int n)
{
   n--;
   if (n>=0)
   {
     print(a,n);
     if(a[n]%2==0)
     {
       printf("%d ",a[n]);
     }
   }
}
```

prints: `2 4`

Comment: Is this how you would do it under the constraints ?  Or because mine is that way? What'd be your cleaner version ?

Comment: I suppose so. But the constraints are ridiculous if you ask me :)

Comment: Yea that was to print the solution of the dp problem using recursion. Instead of posting that directly I thought i'll learn and apply it there.